# How to parse this JSON in django?

Tags: python, json, ajax, django, rest

I am sending data in the below format

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/loginrest/",
    data: JSON.stringify({'user':'admin','password':'zyz'}),
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    error: function(xhr, error){
    console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
},
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

corresponding django code:

```
class LoginView(APIView):


def get(self, request, format=None):
    return Response({'detail': "GET Response"})

def post(self, request, format=None):

    try:
        data = request.DATA
    except ParseError as error:
        return Response(
            'Invalid JSON - {0}'.format(error.detail),
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        )
    print(data)
    print(request.POST)
    try:
        print(QueryDict(request.body).get('user'))
    except:
        print("error")
```

in terminal

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"user":"admin","password":"zyz"}': [u'']}>
<QueryDict: {u'{"user":"admin","password":"zyz"}': [u'']}>
error
```

My question is there any simple way parsing this bypassing substringing
or am i doing anything wrong when sending the JSON in ajax?

Comment: Try *data = request.data*. Then *QueryDict(data).get('user')*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to `JSON.stringify()` the data that you give to jQuery, that's why you get the "double-JSON". See example:

```
var postDataSth = JSON.stringify({asd: 123});

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://url.com',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        data1: postDataSth,
        data2: 'KILLER_QUEEN',
        foo: 'bar'
    },
    success: function (foo) {
        if (foo) {
            console.log(foo.bar);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        console.warn('request failed!');
    }
});
```

Comment: This format is giving me <QueryDict: {u'[object Object]': [u'']}> and I have no idea to parse it.

Comment: @Sayok88 Perhaps you didn't remove the `processData: false` flag?

Comment: no i didnt. Works like a piece of cake mate. Thans a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get data:

```
data = json.loads(request.data)
user = data['user']
```

You already sending json data, so this should work.